# How can I open a post details of my android app from Linkedin app

Tags: android, linkedin-api, deep-linking

I have done it for facebook correctly. But when trying to open it from Linkedin, it is openning in linkedin in-app browser instead of my app. Any idea for url-scheme or if I need to do something in dev account in linkedin is appreciated.

Also Please suggest if I need to do in meta tag of my web url as I did for facebook.

Comment: Did you find the solution.

Comment: Yes. Firebase dynamic links. One stop solution.